# continuum, cofinality must be uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals

> How does it follow from $\kappa < \kappa^{cf \kappa}$ that continuum $2^{\aleph_0}$ cannot be $\aleph_{\omega}$?

It is mentioned everywhere that it is obvious.

Comment: Well what's $\operatorname{cf}\aleph_\omega $ ?

Comment: $2^{\aleph_0}\ne\aleph_\omega$ because $(2^{\aleph_0})^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ while $\aleph_\omega^{\aleph_0}\gt\aleph_\omega.$